# Dagger to Inject a retrofit's service in a tape Task

Tags: java, android, retrofit, dagger, square-tape

I have a retrofit service :

```
public interface MyService {
    @POST("/dosomething")
    String doSomething(@Part("param") MyType param);
}
```

and in a dagger module :

```
@Provides @Singleton
MyService provideService(RestAdapter restAdapter){
    return restAdapter.create(MyMeService.class);
}
```

//note that restAdapter is also provided by that module.

and in a Tape task i'm using that service, I tried :

```
    public class MyTask implements Task<MyTask.Callback> {

        //... omitted for brevity 

        @Inject
         MyService mService;

         @Override
         public void execute(final Callback callback) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                 mService.doSomething(new MyType(...));
                 //...
              }
        }
    }
```

but with this mService is always null.
although MyTask is already added in module's @Module( injects = {...}).

So i tried passing context in task's constructor and injecting my task with something like :

```
MyApplication.get(context).inject(this);
```

But still got mService always null.

Also when injecting MyService instead in my activity and making it just a field in MyTask and then passing it already created. since MyTask is a Tape task (square's tape library) it fails (understandably) when serializing it with:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class: MyService. Forgot to register a type adapter?
```

So is there a way to inject retrofit service class correctly in a Tape Task ?

I'm not sure i explained correctly .. i can provide additional information if needed.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you done objectGraph.inject anywhere?

Comment: yes i'm doing it in onCreate() of my Application class(inject is working correctly in all app activities)

Comment: Did you solve your Problem already? If yes, would you please share your solution with us? :)